# Dedicate some memory to a specific program

Tags: ssh, memory

How do I make a part of main memory dedicated for the system only to use for SSH process?

Every time my server is running some machine learning applications the main memory gets totally full and wont allow anyone even to do an ssh. We have a server with 64GB Main memory.

I want 63 GB can be used for all other processes by all other users, but want to make remaining 1GB exclusively just to start SSH process. Any threads on this would be really of great help.

Comment: This has already been answered: <http://serverfault.com/questions/110929/linux-guarantee-or-reserve-memory-for-a-specific-process>

Comment: @siloko Actually, it's been asked, but not answered there.

Comment: On what unix variant?

Comment: The unix variant is Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Some approaches I can think of:

1. Give the SSH process higher priority.

   ```
   renice -n -10 -p `pidof sshd`
   ```

   With higher priority, ssh server can be frequently scheduled in CPU; as a result, it will less likely be swapped off to disk.
2. Use Systemd's [Resource control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) module to control resource usage of your machine learning program.
   You can use apply `MemoryMax` to a user slice so that all processes started in that user session cannot use more memory than the value specified.  The command is:

   ```
   systemctl set-property MemoryMax=5G user-XXXX.slice
   ```

   Or maybe use the same trick on the ssh server with `MemoryLow`.

Comment: I also heard about `memlockd`, but never try it.

Comment: `renice` has nothing to do with memory. It can help if the system is thrashing but not much. Setting maximum memory for individual sessions doesn't help if there are too many sessions.

Comment: How about imposing resource limitation upon the whole `user.slice` unit, which umbrella all user sessions without interfering `system.slice`?

Comment: Yes, that would work, if you run sshd outside of that slice.

Comment: Indeed, `sshd.service` is usually in `system.slice`.